# Integration of Sign(x)

Tags: integration, continuity

I'm currently trying to create a function for a coding project. It takes a function of the form $ax^{b}$ and integrates it up until a value $c$ beyond which the value is 0.

From this I played around in desmos and came up with the [following function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/euhcj03fyw):

$$
\frac{1}{2}ax^b(1-\operatorname{sgn}(x-c))
$$

When I put the integral of this into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+f%28x%29+%3D+ax%5Eb+%281-sgn%28x-c%29%29%2F2+dx) I get:

$$
-\frac{ax^{b+1}\left(\operatorname{sgn}\left(c-x\right)^{2}-4\operatorname{sgn}\left(c-x\right)-5\right)}{8\left(b+1\right)}
$$

When I type this [into desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qz45h97vkd) however an odd thing happens. When $x > c$ the value of the integral should be constant, but non-zero. In this scenario it is constant but zero... Performing the calculations myself I can understand why the value is zero from the function supplied. Is this just a bug with wolfram or is my understanding of what the output should be incorrect?

---

Note: I am aware that i could use:

```
g(x) => x>c ? f(c) : f(x)
```

but it feels incomplete.

Comment: Am I correctly understand, that you are calculating indefinite integral? Hope you remember, that it's defined accurate up to a constant.

Comment: @zkutch I guess my math knowledge is quite limited. I am ignorant to what definite and indefinite integrals are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is calculating an indefinite integral--that is to say, an antiderivative of the function you provided.  Such an expression is not unique and only needs to satisfy the property that its derivative equals the input function.

If instead you want $$F(x) = \int_{t=-\infty}^x f(t) \, dt, \tag{1}$$ so that $F$ is continuous, then you need to state this.  For instance,

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {a t^b, 0 <= t <= c}, {0, t > c}}],
     {t, -Infinity, x}, Assumptions -> {c > 0, b > 0, a > 0, Element[x, Reals]}]
```

Note that your expression $$f(x; a, b, c) = \frac{1}{2}a x^b (1 - \operatorname{sign}(x - c)) \tag{2}$$ lacks a condition to handle the case $x < 0$, in which case $(1)$ should read $$F(x) = \int_{t=0}^x f(t) \, dt. \tag{3}$$  Such an expression can be integrated properly in *Mathematica* with the command

```
 Integrate[a t^b/2 (1 - Sign[t - c]), {t, 0, x}, 
      Assumptions -> {c > 0, b > 0, a > 0, 0 <= x < Infinity}]
```

Comment: Thanks, sad that the result of the piecewise integral is literally what I wanted to avoid. But thanks for teaching me what indefinite integral is!